# crystal reports XI usage statistics of each report

Tags: crystal-reports

is their anyway to know in crystal reports XI usage statistics of each report

I got instance Manager which is showing some data but not useful can't filter/sort by date, report name. Its allows only user name.

Is their any way i can query crystal Report XI to know usage statistics

Comment: Are you talking about local reports or you have Crystal Reports Server or SAP BOE ?

Comment: crystal reports server